# Linux redirection: << operator

Tags: shell, io-redirection

Can anyone explain when and how to use << operator for input redirection? I've googled enough but couldn't find.

Comment: That's used for a **here document**. Allows you to insert text, verbatim, up to <<HERE (position marked in shell by text before <<.

Comment: Ever heard of the `man` command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `<<` redirection operator introduces a "here document": the text fed into standard input comes just after the redirection.

Here's an example:

```
grep Hello <<EOF
This line won't appear
Hello this one will
Hello again
EOF
```

All the text between `<<EOF` and `EOF` is fed into `grep`. `EOF` isn't special here, the shell takes the word given just after `<<` and uses it as a delimiter.

An interesting variant is `<<-` which strips leading tabs.

See the [`bash` documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Documents) for details.

Answer (score 3):

This operator is used for multiline redirect. See below for example

```
program <<KEYWORD
line1
line2
line3
KEYWORD
```

The above send line1, line2, line3 strings, delimited with newline

You should not have KEYWORD (can be any other word) in the text. And last line with KEYWORD should start from begin, no space, no tab, etc